# Code coverage by developer

Tags: visual-studio, code-coverage

In a discussion with some colleagues in the company, we try to find out a way to have the code coverage by developer.
We know that the code coverage works for the project however we want more granularity on this.
There are any way to achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by "by user"?

Comment: My bad. Developer...

Comment: Even then... what do you mean by "by developer"?

Comment: Imagine that me and you work on the same project. I develop a class with 3 methods. You add one more method. I wrote all unit tests against my 3 methods and you did the same. How can I see the code coverage by developer...

Comment: TFS has a nifty feature called "Annotate" which shows which lines in a file were written by each author, in VS open any TFS-controlled file and right-click in the editor and go Source Control > Annotate. That's the closest you'll get. I'm not aware of any Code Coverage tools that also factor-in source history data.

Comment: Not sure if this helps at all: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/code-lens-for-git-quot-team-activity-view-quot.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will read and try it.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to look at commit histories.

This might interest you:

http://stef.thewalter.net/git-coverage-useful-code-coverage.html

Not sure if you could do it with TFSVC but probably could with TFS-Git

This might be another option as well:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/code-lens-for-git-quot-team-activity-view-quot.aspx